# VBA changing date after specified time in a column

Tags: excel, vba

My problem is that I have a tv-program in Excel. The broadcasting company decided to change days at 8:00 am. I want the day change after 4:00 am. How can I do that in special cases, like there aren't any show starting at 04:xx, but only 05:xx or 06:00. 
So far I came up with this code, but it's only good if I have programs started at 04:00.

```
Sub Gomb1_Kattintás()
    Dim content As String
    Dim airingDate As Date
    Dim airingTime As String

    Range("A2").Select
    airingDate = ActiveCell.Value
    ActiveCell.Offset(1, 0).EntireRow.Insert
    Do Until ActiveCell.Value = "END"        
        airingTime = Format(ActiveCell.Offset(, 1), "hh:mm")
        content = ActiveCell.Offset(, 2).Value

        If InStr(airingTime, "04:") Then
            airingDate = DateAdd("d", 1, airingDate)
            ActiveCell.EntireRow.Resize(3).Insert
            ActiveCell.Offset(1, 0).Value = airingDate
            ActiveCell.Offset(3, 0).Select
        End If      

        If IsEmpty(ActiveCell.Offset(1, 1)) Then
            ActiveCell.Offset(1, 0).EntireRow.Delete
        End If

        If InStr(content, ", ism.") Then
            ActiveCell.Offset(, 6) = 1
            content = Replace(content, ", ism.", "")
            ActiveCell.Offset(, 2).Value = content
        End If
        If InStr(content, ", live") Then
            ActiveCell.Offset(, 7) = 1
            content = Replace(content, ", live", "")
            ActiveCell.Offset(, 2).Value = content
        End If
        If InStr(content, ", HD") Then
            ActiveCell.Offset(, 8) = 1
            content = Replace(content, ", HD", "")
            ActiveCell.Offset(, 2).Value = content
        End If
        If InStr(content, ", premier") Then
            ActiveCell.Offset(, 9) = 1
            content = Replace(content, ", premier", "")
            ActiveCell.Offset(, 2).Value = content
        End If
        ActiveCell.Offset(1, 0).Select
    Loop
End Sub
```

Answer (score 1):

You should use `Hour(time)` function.

Instead of

```vb
If InStr(airingTime, "04:") Then
```

try this:

```vb
If Hour(airingTime) >=4 Then
```

**EDIT 1.**

Modify the line like this:

```vb
If Hour(airingTime) >=4 And Hour(airingTime) <= 7 Then
```

Additionally, move line `airingDate = ActiveCell.Value` after `Do Until ActiveCell.Value = "END"`.

Comment: It would be good, but wouldn't it do the insert at every hour later than 4? It would insert at 5 and 6 and 7... and so on. And this sheet contains a lot days. I want it to insert a row every and new date every day if a show starts at 4 something or later. Then from 04:00 till the next 04:00 it'll be one day.